# НЕ или НИ ? Как правильно в данном случае?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Подскажите какой вариант правилен?

Россия вам не мать, не отец, не сиделка, не отчим.

Россия вам ни мать, ни отец, ни сиделка, ни отчим.

Comment: По мне - предложение с "не" более правильно.  С "ни" нужно отрицание, а его в "вам" не прослеживается.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно:

Россия вам не мать, не отец, не сиделка, не отчим.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

**Отрицательная частица НЕ**

Повторяющаяся частица НЕ может относиться к однородным членам, в том числе при противопоставлении:  Но Кочубей богат и горд не долгогривыми конями, не златом, данью крымских орд,  не родовыми хуторами. Не бродить, не мять в кустах багряных лебеды и не искать следа.  Он не богат, не беден, а среднего достатка.

**Усилительная  частица НИ**

1) Усилительная частица НИ входит в состав повторяющегося соединительного союза НИ…НИ (**при наличии слова с частицей  НЕ**, которая выражает отрицание:  Я не знаю ни его, ни вас. Твои глаза не выражали ни вдохновенья, ни печали.

2) Слово с отрицанием  может быть пропущено, но его можно **восстановить по смыслу**: Ни отзыва, ни слова, ни привета, пустынею меж нами мир лежит. 
Ни в сказке сказать, ни пером описать.

3) Частица НИ в  составе союза НИ…НИ для выражения **полноты отрицания**
   При полноте отрицания  отрицаются **два признака**, предмета или действия, но подразумевается полное отрицание  всех других возможных признаков, предметов и действий. Это тот случай, когда частица НИ одновременно имеет значение и отрицания и усиления: Ворон ни варят, ни жарят.  Здесь ни проехать, ни пройти.

В приведенном примере, скорее, **подразумевается отрицание с противопоставлением:** а кто вам Россия. Причин для выбора усилительной частицы НИ нет. Сравнить: **Он тебе ни мать ни отец** (то есть **никто**, частица НИ используется для отрицания и усиления).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно написание "не". В вашем примере выражается отрицание. Частица "ни" усилительная.

Answer (score 1):

"Россия вам не мать, не отец, не сиделка, не отчим." - корректное предложение (простое перечисление несвязанных напрямую фактов). Развёрнутая форма: "Россия вам не мать, Россия вам не отец, Россия вам не сиделка, Россия вам не отчим". Предложение можно дополнить ("Россия вам не мать, не отец, не сиделка, не отчим, ей на вас плевать"), или достроить ("Россия вам не мать, не отец, не сиделка, не отчим, а сестра").

"Россия вам ни мать, ни отец, ни сиделка, ни отчим." - корректное предложение (усиление акцента на том, что Россия не является ничем из перечисленного). Предложение нельзя достроить ("Россия вам ни мать, ни отец, ни сиделка, ни отчим, а сестра." - неправильно). Развернуть предложение нельзя, поскольку его части связаны.